# Testing Preservation of Application State in Simulator

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I have a problem testing the preservation of the application state in iOS 5: None of the overloads for saving the state are called when I exit the app.

Here is how I overloaded the methods for saving state:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    ...            
    public override bool ShouldSaveApplicationState(UIApplication application, NSCoder coder)
    {
        Data.Save(coder);
        return true;
    }

    public override void WillEncodeRestorableState(UIApplication application, NSCoder coder)
    {
        Data.Save(coder);
    }
```

And here are the methods that I used for exiting the app, as far as I understood it, each one of these should trigger the state preservation calls (but they dont):

- press the home button
- calling `UIApplication.SharedApplication.PerformSelector(new Selector("terminateWithSuccess"), null, 0f);`
- calling `Environment.Exit(0);` (this will cause the application to hang)
- Set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to true in `Info.plist` and press the home button in the simulator

So my question is: Why are the methods for saving state not called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question on the [forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/9300/ios-5-state-preservation) that points back here state that you are using iOS 5.

State preservation was added by Apple in iOS 6. Earlier iOS versions won't call your overrides.

Answer (score 1):

From the Apple docs:

> Be aware that the system automatically deletes an app’s preserved
>   state when the user force quits the app. Deleting the preserved state
>   information when the app is killed is a safety precaution. (The system
>   also deletes preserved state if the app crashes at launch time as a
>   similar safety precaution.) If you want to test your app’s ability to
>   restore its state, you should not use the multitasking bar to kill the
>   app during debugging. Instead, use Xcode to kill the app or kill the
>   app programmatically by installing a temporary command or gesture to
>   call exit on demand.

Try pressing the Home button instead.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Sorry I forgot to mention that I did try just pressing the home button. I read the documentation, it just does not explicitly mention how to "kill the app programmatically by calling exit on demand". I tried calling `Environment.Exit(0)` is this wrong? What would be the right call?